# split a column based on a delimiter and then unpivot the result with preserving other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, delimiter, unpivot

I need to split a column to multiple rows and then unpivot them by preseving a/multiple columns, how can I achive this in Python3

See below example

```
import numpy as np
data=np.array(['a0','a1,a2','a2,a3'])
pk=np.array([1,2,3])
df=pd.DataFrame({'data':data,'PK':pk})
df
```

[image]

```
df['data'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(str(x).split(","))).stack()
```

[image]

What I need is:

```
data  pk
 a0   1
 a1   2
 a2   2
 a2   3
 a3   3
```

Is there any way to achieve this without merge and resetting indexes as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286179/splitting-and-unpivoting-a-column-in-pandas#_=_)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Explode is the keyword (thx to wwnde for pointing it out) for searching this and can be done easily in Python with using existing libraries

First step is converting the column with a delimiter to a list

```
df=df.assign(Data=df.data.str.split(","))
```

[image]

and then explode

```
df.explode('Data')
```

[image]

if you are reading from Excel and Pandas detect a list of number as int and if you need to do the explode multiple times then this is the code and results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Convert column data into list and explode the data frame

Data

```
data=np.array(['a0','a1,a2','a2,a3'])
pk=np.array([1,2,3])
df=pd.DataFrame({'data':data,'PK':pk})
df=spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Solution

```
df.withColumn('data', F.explode(F.split(col('data'),','))).show()
```

Comment: Thx, what are F and spark? I installed spark through pip but I am receiving Module 'spark' has no attribute 'createDataFrame'

Comment: Have you tried the community edition? https://community.cloud.databricks.com/login.html or check how to set up spark in Jupiter, there are countless videos and and posts

Comment: I am working on a server and I leave installing spark as the last solution, needs to get some approvals which take time. Seems not very straight process

Comment: You should not have tagged your question `Pyspark `then. I will edit tag and add `pandas`. If that's the case then  use `df=df.assign(data=df['data'].str.split(',')).apply(lambda x:x.explode())`

Comment: Thanks for the code, I was not  planning to use pyspark, sorry for the confusion,

Comment: Thats fair enough